# Calling parent method from child?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, oop, inheritance

I have studied that when a class inherits from parent class, then all properties & functions of parent class come to child class. Now I have declared a method in parent class so that it remains for all child classes. Now I want to call method of parent from child. How should I do it?

```
class BaseController: UIViewController {

    func addNavBar() {

        //some code
    }

}


class SignupController: BaseController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.addNavBar()
    }
}
```

Comment: Here 'self' would refer to the current class which is SignUpController and your method is actually inside parent class BaseController. For accessing parent class you use 'super' keyword. so replace self with super like super.addNavBar()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have class **B** derived from class **A**...

```
class BaseController: UIViewController {
    func addNavBar() { print("...") }
}

class SignupController: BaseController {

}
```

In class **B**, you can call a method from class **A** by typing

```
super.addNavBar() **OR** self.addNavBar()
```

...depending on whether or not you have re-implemented that method in a subclass with `override` keyword.  If you **did not** `override` it (and you don't necessarily have to), then those two calls are equivalent.

On the other hand, if you added your own implementation in **B**:

```
override func addNavBar() {
    print("My implementation of addNavBar")
}
```

calling `super.addNavBar()` will call implementation from **A**. And calling `self.addNavBar()` will call your local implementation, both being acceptable from your subclass. And when your subclass calls `super` as well:

```
override func addNavBar() {
    super.addNavBar()
    print("My implementation of addNavBar")
}
```

calling `self.addNavBar()` from subclass will call implementation from both. Keep in mind, that if you don't call superclass implementation in your `override` method, you replace this implementation.

In most `UI`-classes, it's highly recommended to call superclass method upon overriding, in order to avoid any abnormal behavior, unless you provide sufficient implementation on your own (e.g. reposition or draw elements).

Comment: When we overirde any method then why we call superclass method first.like in viewdidload we always call superclass viewdidload

Comment: You don't have to call superclass method. It's entirely up to you. Some exceptions  apply in Swift, e.g. when you override designated initializer.

Comment: But why would call super class method if i have overridden it?

Comment: It depends on your situation. You may want to call super or you may want to replace particular implementation completely.

Comment: In UI-related tasks, such as `draw(rect: )` you are supposed to call super unless you manually redraw elements with your code. Although you don't have to, if you understand responsibility.

Comment: Thanks for sharing information.But i would like to dig it more so get deep knowledge.Can you suggest better place to study

Comment: Here's a good read: https://www.raywenderlich.com/160728/object-oriented-programming-swift

Answer (score 4):

You are using super class method so you can call method using `super` keyword as like below.

```
class BaseController: UIViewController {

    func addNavBar() {

        //some code
    }

}

class SignupController: BaseController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.addNavBar()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class basecontroller:UIViewControler { 
    func addNavBar() { 
        //some code 
    }
}  

class SignupController:BaseController {
    func viewDidLoad() {
        self.addNavBar() //this will call parent method if you are not override
    }

    override func addNavBar() { 
        super.addNavBar() //In case of overriding you need to use super
        //some code 
    }

}
```